# load all templates at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js

The following code loads templates.

```
tpl = {

    // Hash of preloaded templates for the app
    templates: {},

    // Recursively pre-load all the templates for the app.
    // This implementation should be changed in a production environment. All the template files should be
    // concatenated in a single file.
    loadTemplates: function(names, callback) {

        var that = this;

        var loadTemplate = function(index) {
            var name = names[index];
            console.log('Loading template: ' + name);
            $.get('tpl/' + name + '.html', function(data) {
                that.templates[name] = data;
                index++;
                if (index < names.length) {
                    loadTemplate(index);
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }

        loadTemplate(0);
    },

    // Get template by name from hash of preloaded templates
    get: function(name) {
        return this.templates[name];
    }

};
```

and u can load templates like

```
tpl.loadTemplates(['header', 'wine-details', 'wine-list-item'], function() {

});
```

But here the templates are defined in seperate html file.

Is it possible all my templates are defined in one html file and i load them all together.
Do i need to write some kind of parser. The reason is for my home page i have 40 templates and I dont want to create 40 Html template pages instead it would be i can keep them in one single html page and than load them all together.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you don't need to be doing it like this.

Check this: https://github.com/requirejs/text

```
define([
    'some/module',
    'text!some/module.html',
    'text!some/module.css'
], function (SomeModule, HtmlFile, CssFile) {
    'use strict';

    // ....
}
```

This can load text resources. When you are ready to deploy your app you can compile all your js files and templates into a single minified file using [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js). You can do this via command line, or as a grunt or gulp task.

There are many template libraries which you can find requirejs plugins for (often extended off that text plugin ^^). For example this one for Handlebars https://github.com/jfparadis/requirejs-handlebars or this one for underscore https://github.com/jfparadis/requirejs-tpl. Just google search "requirejs «template engine name»".

---

If you want to have multiple templates in one html file you need a way to separate them. The nicest way to do this is using the new [template](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) tag.

Comment: Ye but for this i have to create 40 html files because I have 40 html templates

Comment: The whole point of MVC architecture is that you separate your code out into modules. If you want to develop all in one file you might as well not use an MVC library. The whole idea is that views have their own templates!

Comment: yes i am not using anz MVC library. I want to avoid using libraries as far as possible.... I am just curious if there is any parser which can load the templates from one single file

Comment: Just use [RequireJS Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html)! It's exactly what you need, it'll combine all javascript files and templates to one javascript file, but you will be able to require your templates separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can, define templates single file, under different container with Ids. load single html the way you are loading here, create a jquery node with template html, run through children read id attribute and save html of each child saved as `that.templates[id_you_read] = child.html();`

But this is not the right way of doing stuff. use requirejs with text plugin as in the prev answer.